# Double-click autofill - dynamic based on adjacent cell

Tags: excel, vba, double-click

I need to do:

[image: Excel Autofill]

I am using the normal auto-fill function in Excel (double click the dot on the side of a cell) to copy the contents to the sub cells, so in this case clicking the dot in Cell A1 will do this:

[image]

I need a script that will repeat the process down the entire column, until there are no more values in the adjacent cell.

Comment: Wait, did you want it to auto increment the numbers or just repeat `Table 1` until it gets to `Table 2`? If your screen shot is your desired behaviour then I don't see what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: To add to @Alain's question, what should be below Table 2 in cell A7?  Table 3?

Comment: Why don't you try something, and come back to us with any specific problems...

Comment: Sorry.. my sample was wrong,, yes i would have no need for the current setup, i will update the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably this is what you're looking for:

```
Option Explicit
Sub FillInTheBlanks()
    Dim StartCell As Range, EndCell As Range
    Set StartCell = ActiveCell
    Set EndCell = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, StartCell.Offset(0, 1).Column).End(xlUp)

    Dim currentText As String
    Dim i As Long
    For i = StartCell.Row To EndCell.Row
        If Not IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, StartCell.Row)) Then
            currentText = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, StartCell.Row).Text
        Else
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i, StartCell.Row).Value = currentText
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

That code with perform the following:

[image]

---

If you really want what's in your screenshot, then you'll need to do this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub FillInTheBlanks()
    Dim StartCell As Range, EndCell As Range, NextCell As Range
    Set StartCell = ActiveCell
    Set EndCell = Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, StartCell.Offset(0, 1).Column).End(xlUp)

    While StartCell.Row < EndCell.Row
        Set NextCell = StartCell.Offset(1, 1).End(xlDown).Offset(0, -1)
        StartCell.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range(StartCell, NextCell), Type:=xlFillDefault
        Set StartCell = NextCell.Offset(1, 0)
    Wend
End Sub
```

Which does this:

[image]

Comment: `UsedRange` needs to be qualified, e.g., `ActiveSheet.UsedRange`.

Comment: @DougGlancy 'Need' is a strong word. It's not true in this case - if this action is to take place on a selection, (i.e. select a cell and activate a shortcut key - which is clearly how the code is written since it uses 'ActiveCell') then the data context is implied.

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов Because it uses poorly named variables, implied data contexts, offsets, and doesn't properly account for boundary cases, like when there's only one row in the next column over, etc. In proper VBA, any use of the keywords `Range`, `Cell`, `Selection`, `ActiveCell`, `UsedRange`, etc... should be preceded by an explicit reference to the Workbook and Worksheet the range belongs to.

Comment: gotcha :) if there are so many problems with the code then why post it?

Comment: Alain, I say "need" because it didn't compile for me - "Unknown Variable" compiler message.  If I type ? UsedRange.Address in the debug window I get "Object Required."  Both are solved when qualifying with "Activesheet."  Excel 2010.

Comment: @DougGlancy That's curious. Excel 2007 has no such problem. That's a good non-backwards compatibility thing to keep in mind! Editing now.

Comment: Yes, I was surprised and triple-checked.  I suppose there may be something else going on, but just making the change back and forth changed the behavior.  Anyways, glad to clear it up, so you won't think I'm just fussy for no reason!

Comment: @Alain WOW, thanks.. that is spot on what i was looking for!... ( the first scenario)... this will save a lot of trouble in the future!..  as you said... all you do is save as a module , select the data you want in excel and initiate the macro... Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can do this from the keyboard...

- Select Column A
- Choose *Home | Find & Select | Goto Special... Blanks OK*
- Press [=] [up arrow] [ctrl+Enter]

To remove formulas, select Column A, copy and paste-special values.

[image]

Comment: This is nifty! If we're trying to simplify this using the keyboard, in Excel 2003, you can shortcut to the second step with `<CTRL>+<G>`.

Comment: Oh wow!... this is really great, shows the power of Excel ( and having people that know these advanced functions) ... Thanks for this!