# Autofill from cell above if adjacent cell is not empty + match

Tags: excel, vba, autofill

I'm not that familiar with VBA, so please bear with me.

My question is related to this link: [Double-click autofill - dynamic based on adjacent cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11262019/double-click-autofill-dynamic-based-on-adjacent-cell)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvISH.png)

However, the attributes are located in another column (for example Column E). I've tried tweaking the code, but to no avail.

Comment: By the way, I need to use VBA since it can contain more than 20,000 items which then needs to be inserted on another program. Hope someone could help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
Sub FillBlanks()
Dim lr As Long
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row   'Assuming Attributes are in Column E
On Error Resume Next
'Assuming you want to fill blanks in column A
With Range("A1:A" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    .Formula = "=R[-1]C"
    .Value = .Value
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello! By the way, I'll be filling blanks in Column A.Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Comment: Hello! By the way, I'll be filling blanks in Column B.                   Unfortunately, it doesn't work. If I have the first item as EQ-1 on B21, then have 10 blank cells after, EQ-1 is autofilled, but once the 11th cell (B32) has EQ-2 on it, EQ-1 still fills the cells below and not EQ-2. Moreover, N/A also appears (I'm not so sure as to why.)

Comment: If you are trying to fill the blanks in column B, replace the line With Range("A1:A" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks) with With Range("B1:B" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks) and replace B1 with the first cell in column B where you want to start filling blank from. So if it is B21, replace B1 with B21.

Comment: Test the code in this file by clicking the button on Sheet1: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ukjcsonlf2r5wd3/FillBlanksInColB.xlsm?dl=0

Comment: I've already changed the code yesterday, but it still doesn't work. If it helps, here is how it looks:

Comment: What doesn't work? Did you try the file? Is data layout different from the file I provided you? Would be better if you can provide a sample workbook to look at.

Comment: I couldn't open the file you provided. The attribute column also has blanks in it, maybe that's why it's not working. I'll try sending a picture. https://files.fm/u/zhwhh4pe

Comment: The attribute column is the one with D and N to it, referring to their shifts.

Comment: Images are hard to work with. Upload the workbook on Google drive and share the link with me. The code I offered is very simple code and can be tweaked easily e.g. the line lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row finds the last row used in the column E, replace "E" with column letter as per your workbook and the code inside the With block "With Range("A1:A" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)" fills the blanks in col A starting from Row1 and all you need is to replace the Range("A1:A" & lr) part and the starting row number which is 1 right now. That's it. Still hard to understand and tweak?